# テンキー表示時にスクロール画面の下部が切れる。

Tags: monaca

皆様いつもお世話になります。
過去質問を捜したのですが見つからないので（もしくは努力不足）、どなたか回答願います。

アプリで三角関数の計算結果を求める物を作っております。

HTMLの配置は
「トップへ戻る」
「メニューへ戻る」

三角関数の図形

「各種入力項目」
「計算実行ボタン」

「計算結果」
（ここまで　添付画像　１）

---

入力を実行するとテンキーが現れます。
しかしテキストエリアに被ってしまい、以下入力するところが見えなくなります。
（添付画像　２）

---

そしてテンキーの表示をやめるとスクロール出来ない状態になります。
（添付画像　３）
画像１では確認できた　長さ＝　のところが見えなくなってます。

どのような事が問題なのでしょうか？
どなたか解決策を教えてください。
お忙しいところ申し訳ございませんが何卒宜しく御願い申し上げます。

[image: 添付画像 １][image: 添付画像 ２][image: 添付画像 ３]

Comment: Myakuさま　お忙しい中回答いただき感謝いたします。Androidの場合はその様な症状が出るのですか。教えていただいた箇所を勉強してみたいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Androidの問題ですね
iOSだと上に引き上げてくれるのですが、
Androidでは入力が上に引き上げてもらえないという状態ですよね

対処するとしたら、`onfocus`と`onblur`でイベントを取得し、
Androidのみ入力中のテキストボックスをスクロールして手動で上に上げてやればいいかと思います。

ただし、HTMLドキュメントサイズ以上にはスクロールできないので、
残りスクロール量が画面サイズ以下になったら一時的にHTMLのサイズを引き伸ばしてあげる必要があるかと思います。

また、CSSでも対処可能ですね、
対象を`position:fixed`などにして画面の上部に一瞬移動してやればいいかもしれません。

Comment: Myakuさま　お忙しい中回答いただき感謝いたします。Androidの場合はその様な症状が出るのですか。教えていただいた‌​箇所を勉強してみたいと思います。ありがと‌​うございました。